Had a smart contract do a increase allowence function on my wallet and it stole 3800 BEAM ON BSC
Connected trust wallet on airdrop site and it connected did 2 0.004 cent transactions and i went to BSC Scam to revoke the ok i gave it to connected to my wallet and by time i came back it took 3800 BEAM coins of BSC out of my trust wallet

I’m voting to close this question because there doesn't appear to be a question to answer

If you want someone to take a look you should provide more details wallet, contracts, transactions, etc.
